# Can't store $_SESSION variables

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables

I develop this set of 2 scripts in order to use $_SESSION variables to check if the user is logged in. I didn't use cookies because I didn't want to get to that "jazz" yet.

Here is the login.php

```
require 'host.php'; // Connection to database

$message = '';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if ((!$username) || (!$password)) {
        $message ='Preencha todos os campos.';
    } else{
        $username = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$username);
        $password = sha1($password);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM utilizadores WHERE nome_utilizador='$username' AND palavra_chave='$password' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysql_query($sql) or die();
        if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 1) {
            // Logged in stuff
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
            while ($consulta = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                $id = $consulta['id_utilizador']; // ID of username.
            }
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            $message = '<a href="calendario.php">Clique aqui para ir para o calendário.</a>'; // Message that is shown to redirect to another page.
        } else{
            $message = 'Os dados que inseriu estão incorrectos!'; // Data inserted is incorrect.
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the file that checks if the user is logged in

```
session_start();

include 'host.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $password = $_SESSION['password'];
    //Verificar se o user existe.
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM utilizadores WHERE id_utilizador='$id' AND palavra_chave='$password' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die('Could not connect.');
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        header('Location: logout.php');
    } else{
        // Logged in stuff
        $logged = 1;
    }
} else{
    $logged = 0;
}
```

The want i would do to check the session is include the file in every page and check is $logged == 0.

But it isn't storing session data from page to page.

Hope you can help me!

Thanks!

Comment: are you using session_start() on ALL pages?

Comment: If I include verify_session.php in every page, yes I am

Comment: Have you tried putting session_start in login.php at the top of the php file rather than halfway down the page?

Comment: On the second script, is the query checking to see if the user exists, if so should the mysql_num_rows be == 0

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: The session_start() needs to be called before any output is echoed out.

Comment: Also if you're using header redirects I have had that lose the session before, you may need to hardcode the session id to the location of the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

your id variable is inside the while loop and cant be read outside the while loop. so thats why the session is storing nothing

try to define id variable   before the while loop

```
   $id = "";
   while ($consulta = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  ......
```

you can try if it echo something after while loop 
like that

```
  echo $id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed the problem!

All I add to do is change the verify_session.php, and in mysql_num_rows() put it == 0, instead  of > 0.

Thanks for all the help guys!